# Missing BOOTMGR

Tags: boot

By mistake I have removed the window bootmgr when I was using UBUNTU OS-installer/uninstaller. My netbook does not have a CD-ROM drive so, I have been trying to installed Ubuntu again by using the USB drive but sadly it failed. I have already attempted to change the priority boot too.

Please Help Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm afraid your question has so few details it's impossible to answer. I would recommend trying other [avenues of support for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/support) that may be more suitable, such as the IRC channel.

Answer (score 1):

If you can obtain a Windows installation ISO (these are not hard to find as Microsoft makes them freely available), you can create a bootable USB from that ISO using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Once you boot from that USB, rather than running an install you can enter the recovery console (google it). Once there, execute `fixmbr` and `fixboot`.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) article on the ubuntu wiki will help you if you actually have an installation of Ubuntu you want to keep (your question did not seem clear on that point) - following my instructions will remove Ubuntu's bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy BOOTMGR from others computer,because the BOOTMGR is same your and others
,or using you usb to get an Windows7 ISO can booting and installing,chose to repair your
computer not install,hope that can help you.